# Training data is left skewed, however the resulting predictions are normally distributed

Tags: random-forest

I am training a random forest regression model in R using 3 years of historical data. This is the histogram of the left skewed y data:

[image]

When I use the model to predict on new data the results are normally distributed, this is the histogram of the normally distributed forecasted ŷ data:

[image]

Is this a normal operation of the random forest algorithm? A problem with my implementation?

Comment: The results would have to depend on the new data, wouldn't they?  Please tell us how the new data compare to the training data.

Comment: The data is ticket tracking data for a variable process. The training data is ~6000 records of historical, closed tickets, from the past 3 years. The new data is ~1400 currently open tickets. As an experiment I ran both test and train data through a trained model, and received left skewed data. I am predicting the number of days the process will take for an open ticket, using the historical data.

Comment: I wonder - the left skew is tickets that close quickly.. and tickets that are currently open, trend towards being tickets that take longer to close (else they would have already closed).

Comment: Your first plot shows data that would be characterized as strongly *right* (positively) skewed.  It sounds like your second plot consists of data that aren't really comparable to the training data.  What do the numbers represent?  If they are days open, then you need some form of *survival analysis* to handle the distinction between open and closed tickets.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for pointing me in the direction of survival analysis, I am reading about it now.